This interaction failed error on custom discord bot
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$", intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{bot.user.name} is now awake and ready to help!')

@bot.command()
async def suggestion(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Click the button to submit an anonymous suggestion.", view=SuggestionView())

class SuggestionView(discord.ui.View):
    @discord.ui.button(label="Submit Suggestion", style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary)
    async def submit_suggestion(self, button: discord.ui.Button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        try:
            await interaction.response.send_modal(SuggestionModal())
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error sending modal: {e}")
            await interaction.response.send_message("An error occurred while trying to send the modal.", ephemeral=True)

class SuggestionModal(discord.ui.Modal):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(title="Anonymous Suggestion")
        self.add_item(discord.ui.InputText(label="Your Suggestion", style=discord.InputTextStyle.long))

    async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        suggestion = self.children[0].value
        channel = discord.utils.get(interaction.guild.channels, name="suggestions")
        if channel:
            try:
                await channel.send(f"Anonymous Suggestion:\n{suggestion}")
                await interaction.response.send_message("Your suggestion has been submitted anonymously.", ephemeral=True)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error sending suggestion: {e}")
                await interaction.response.send_message("An error occurred while sending your suggestion.", ephemeral=True)
        else:
            await interaction.response.send_message("The suggestions channel was not found.", ephemeral=True)

@bot.event
async def on_application_command_error(ctx, error):
    print(f"An error occurred: {error}")

bot.run('BOT_Token')

I managed to set up a bot and invite it to my server, although when I type my command $suggestion it replies with a button, when i press this button I get an "This interaction failed" message. No error popup on my terminal..
I've tried disabling fire wall, I've tried opening discord web, cant figure out the issue, any help is appreciated!
